# Ruby and Chef: Resolve and Replace Values in a hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, chef-infra

I am using opscode chef to automate the deployment of MySQL cluster. I want to put the desired hosts into a JSON file, then let chef resolve those hostnames to internal IP addresses, then set the IP addresses as variables.

I have a simple hash that looks like this:

```
    [data_bag_item["dbclstr", "dbclstr", 
{
"id"=>"dbclstr", 
"nodes"=>{"sql1"=>"cdb1.ex.net", 
      "sql2"=>"cdb2.ex.net", 
      "mgmnt"=>"cdb1.ex.net", 
      "db1"=>"cdb1.ex.net", 
      "db2"=>"cdb2.ex.net"
}}]]
```

I want to basically grab the nodes key then go through all the key values in the hash grab each key/value then parse the value through my search function that returns the ip address then assign the value to that key.

```
dbclstr = search(:dbclstr).first # Loads json into hash

privip = dbclstr["nodes"] # grabs node hash from hash (turns into a mash?)
privip = privip.to_hash # turn mash to hash

privip.map { |key,value| # maps the keys and values of the hash.

item = search(:node,"name:value") #loads machine data from chef into object
value = "#{item[0][:cloud][:private_ips]}" # extracts ip address from object and sets it as value, done?

}
```

Well this doesn't work.

Individually I can resolve hostnames to IP addresses, but I don't really understand how to grab each key and value, resolve the value, then replace it with the resolved value.

Comment: a) What you have there is not an array, it's a hash of key/value pairs. b) What do you mean it "doesn't work"? (I cleaned up some of your code that was obviously invalid Ruby, but I suspect that wasn't just what you needed.)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, when you have a Hash and want to update all key/value pairs to have new values, you have several options:

**If the values are strings or arrays, and you want new strings or arrays**

```
# Using String#replace or Array#replace to swap out the object's contents
my_hash.each do |key,value|
  value.replace( new_value )
end
```

**If the values are strings, and you want to replace text, updating them in-place**

```
my_hash.each do |key,str|
  str.sub! 'foo', 'bar'  # Replace just the first occurrence
  str.gsub! /foo/, 'bar' # Replace every occurrence
end
```

**Other Cases (more generic)**

```
# Option 1: modify the hash in-place
my_hash.each{ |key,value| my_hash[key] = new_value }

# Option 2a: create a new hash (Ruby 1.9 only)
new_hash = Hash[ my_hash.map{ |key,value| [key, new_value] } ]

# Option 2b: create a new hash (Ruby 1.8+)
new_hash = Hash[ *my_hash.map{ |key,value| [key, new_value] }.flatten ]
```